# how to post nothing to server but didn't make it null

Tags: android, post, http-post

I have a problem when i want to post something to server but I don't want to change everything.

The problem is when i not fill something and post it to server it will send null and the old data is change into null.

**this is my example code**

```
            json.put("user_id", 6);
            json.put("status", status_id);
            json.put("comment", ket);
            json.put("photo", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encodedImage);
```

for example I just want to change status but if I don't fill comment or photo it will send null. Please help how to solve it

Comment: If you don't want to change it than don't send those parameter in the request. else pass the data that you got from the server

Comment: sometimes i want to change it but sometimes not. it an optional

Comment: Than check for null on your side. If it's not null then pass it else don't. And also take care of this from server side. If they made this parameters optional or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should be handled at server side** instead of client side i.e. your Android App side.

You need to modify server side logic something like this *`Update only those values/properties which are not null, if null don't update`*.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table don't make comment/photo not null. If you did that, just don't pass those parameters with json.put and it should work.

Or pass it as a null or "".